# How to read from a serial port using xpcom from Firefox?

Tags: cross-platform, firefox-addon, serial-port, xpcom

I want to use xpcom to connect Mozilla Firefox to a serial port. The final result should be an xpi addon that can be installed on various environments (cross-platform Windows/Linux with Firefox 3.*). Where should I start?

I have found an example here: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=19&t=1083965&start=0 , but I think that code will only work on Linux... Can I do something similar in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

XPCOM is not for serial port communication. From what I can see, it is any interface to MS COM.

Please research your questions a little.

Comment: I've been researching a little these days and I have come to the conclusion that I have to create an XPCOM C++ component for that. I've already made some progress on creating an extension that works on Ubuntu. Next step is to make something similar for Windows and maybe after that I'll merge the two components into one cross-platform component.

Comment: Hi Huper, I'm solving the exact same problem. Did you finish the work on your XPCOM component? Is it possible to see the component or maybe a part of it?

Comment: Yes, I have managed to develop a component that can be used in other Firefox extensions very easily, but works only on Ubuntu. Mostly i followed the instructions found here: [Creating a C++ XPCOM component](http://www.iosart.com/firefox/xpcom/) It is quite customized for my needs but maybe something general could be implemented.